NIC never uses r8168 driver
Running Ubuntu 24.04 server. In an effort to get wake on lan working on a Realtek RTL8125 NIC, I tried switching from the r8169 driver to r8168-dkms, but the latter never gets used by the system. After installing r8168-dkms (sudo apt install r8168-dkms) I blacklisted r8169 and updated initramfs, but all that yielded is no internet connection: the ethernet interface in question never comes up (empty on ip a)
Is there a way to make sure r8168 gets used by the NIC?
